# R moving average between data frame variables

Tags: r, variables, moving-average

I am trying to find a solution but haven't, yet.
I have a dataframe structured as follows:

```
country City 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019
France  Paris 23   34   54   12   23   21
US       NYC   1    2    2    12   95  54
```

I want to find the moving average for every 3 years (i.e. 2014-16, 2015-17, etc) to be placed in ad-hoc columns.

```
country City 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2014-2016  2015-2017  2016-2018  2017-2019
France  Paris 23   34   54   12   23   21    37          33.3      29.7        18.7  
US       NYC   1    2    2    12   95  54    etc           etc     etc          etc
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end we apply `rollmean` to each column in the transpose of the data and then transpose back.  We `rollapply` the appropriate paste command to create the names.

```
library(zoo)

DF2 <- DF[-(1:2)]
cbind(DF, setNames(as.data.frame(t(rollmean(t(DF2), 3))), 
  rollapply(names(DF2), 3, function(x) paste(range(x), collapse = "-"))))
```

giving:

```
  country  City 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2014-2016 2015-2017 2016-2018 2017-2019
1  France Paris   23   34   54   12   23   21 37.000000 33.333333  29.66667  18.66667
2      US   NYC    1    2    2   12   95   54  1.666667  5.333333  36.33333  53.66667
```

**2)** This could also be expressed using dplyr/tidyr/zoo like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)

DF %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(country, City)) %>%
  group_by(country, City) %>%
  mutate(value = rollmean(value, 3, fill = NA),
    name = rollapply(name, 3, function(x) paste(range(x), collapse="-"), fill=NA)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  drop_na %>%
  pivot_wider %>%
  left_join(DF, ., by = c("country", "City"))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "country City 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019
France  Paris 23   34   54   12   23   21
US       NYC   1    2    2    12   95  54 "
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.
Could you please explain how this works, though? I would avoid to bother the community with silly questions in the future...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Another question: the first solution only consider the countries in which figures for all the 3 years are present. Would it be possible to include even the years in which just one or two figures are present and having the average of  1 or 2 years?

Comment: @ G. Grothendieck:  something like this, you mean?
 
`     cbind(ext_pov, setNames(as.data.frame(t(rollapply(t(ext_pov_4), 3, FUN=mean, partial=TRUE))),                                       rollapply(names(ext_pov_4), 3, FUN=mean, partial = TRUE, function(x) paste(range(x), collapse = "-"))))     `

Comment: @ G. Grothendieck: you are right in theory, nevertheless I am even trying to flag whether 1 data, 2 or 3 are included in the triennial considered for each country, but that is another issue. In any case, the script still is not considering the triennials including 1 or more NAs.